# Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check" - symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I know this is a common problem. And several questions on this topic have been posted. **I have tried all those solutions recommended in those questions, but none worked.**

I found that this problem occurs if I put my `form_login` behind a `firewall`. But I'm not having any extra layer in firewall so the path should be simple as described in documentation.

My **security.yml**

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        Joy\JoyBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:        sha512
            encode_as_base64: true
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: JoyBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/signup, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My **routing.yml** in `app/config`

```
# app/config/routing.yml
login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: JoyBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    path: /login_check

joy_hello:
    resource: "@JoyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /
```

So I'm performing login check while accessing `app_dev.php/` But it's showing that error after pressing submit in login form.

> Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you
>   forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration? 404
>   Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

I tried

```
login_path: /login
check_path: /login_check
```

Didn't work. What I'm missing ?? Please help.....

Comment: what does `php app/console router:debug`
 says?

Comment: @Flask I'm new to symfony2. So don't know all the meanings. Giving that command shows a list of name,method,scheme,host,path. And in that list there is login_check ANY ANY ANY /login_check

Comment: `login_check:
    path: /login_check`
set a default controller and action

Comment: @crack where?? my routing.yml already contains login_check: path: /login_check

Comment: are you using fosuserbundle?

Comment: @crack nope. I'm following this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: @AtanuCSE, checkout this git hub repo. You have all you need in that project (even fb login) https://github.com/goors/boring. You do not make controller for login_check.

Comment: Not related to your issue, however, moving your dev-specific things into a `security_dev.yml` file will help you keep things tidy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The route `login_check` is not behind the firewall because the `login_check` route pattern matches the `login` firewall which has no security.

```
login:
    pattern:  ^/login     # This matches /login_check
    security: false
```

Solution 1: Change this to

```
login:
    pattern:  ^/login$
    security: false
```

Solution 2: Remove the `login` firewall altogether and add this rule to `access_control`

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: this solution now keeps circulating in same page. Login page is coming over and over again after clicking submit.

Comment: But the user is already logged in, according to Symfony's profiler? I guess that if you want to go to another route after a successful login, yo have to make an authentication handler, that implements the `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`. Or the easiest way, try to access a secured route, and if you are not logged in, Symfony will redirect you to the login page, and after a successful login, it will automatically redirect to the requested page.

Comment: let me try more. I think this will work. May be I'm missing something else

Answer (score 0):

In **security.yml** try setting the provider at the `secured_area` section:

```
secured_area:
    provider: administrators
    pattern: ^/
    anonymous: ~
```