# Symfony2 not successful login

Tags: symfony, authentication

To use the application which I implement the user must login first. The login form appears on the "/" url.

So I create the following "security.yml".

```
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                success_handler: app_user_handler_login
                failure_handler: app_user_handler_login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            switch_user: {role: ROLE_ADMIN}
    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AppUserBundle:User, property: username }

    encoders:
        App\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: ~
        ROLE_TEACHER: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_EDITOR: [ROLE_TEACHER]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_EDITOR]
```

My routing file have the following content.

```
login:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppSecurityBundle:Default:index}

login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path: /logout
```

Now if i call the url "/app_dev.php/" the login form appears and if i enter a valid username with password i receive the following error.

"No route found for "POST //login_check"

But if i call the url "/" or "/app_dev.php" everything is ok, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the login_path and check_path be preceded with a "/" like the logout path?

Comment: There are several questions already about this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950149/unable-to-find-the-controller-for-path-login-check-symfony2

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866123/symfony2-authentication-login-check-path-not-found

Comment: This solve my problem partially. Now i can successfull login but i do not understand why the "/" exists as trailing slash after "app_dev.php" this trigger another problem with the profiler. On the prod enviorment the trailing slash not exisits and everything is fine.